Sochatchov on renewing the soul with the Shofar
In the sefer Eretz Tzvi, by Rabbi Aryeh Tzvi Frumer it says (Eretz Tzvi, Moadim, Newer Version, Vol. 2, p, 48):

ויש לומר הענין בזה לפי מה ששמעתי מאדמו"ר הזקן זצוקלה"ה מסוכטשוב דע"י
שופר מתעורר הכוח מהא דכתיב (בראשית ב' ז'): ויפח באפיו נשמת חיים, אז יש
התחדשות הבריאה עכד"ק.
"We can explain this according to what I heard from the elder Rebbe of Sochatchov, of blessed memory, that through the shofar, the power of what is written (Genesis 2:7): 'He breathed into his nostrils the breath of life,' is awakened, and then the creation is renewed — thus spoke the holy elder."

Does someone know where to find this in the works of Sochatchov? I heard it is from the Avnei Nezer, but I am not sure. Rav Daniel Glatstein shlita mentions the Avnei Nezer, and that he quotes from the Zohar, that says that when the posuk says "He breathed into his nostrils the breath of life", it is "Baal Tokea". But I don't know where to find this, and if this is the same as what the Eretz Tzvi quotes.

Do you know that he ever wrote it down? Maybe he just said it orally and Rav Frumer heard it.

@DoubleAA As I recall, Rav Daniel Glatstein shlita mentions that the avnei nezer explained it, but I found no sources.

The Avnei Nezer discusses a vaguely similar idea in נאות הדשא (Rosh HaShana, §2-3): קול שופר הוא קול נפשי בלבד, המשפעת… במדרש (ויק”ר כ”ט) בשעה שישראל תוקעין בשופר הקב”ה מתמלא עליהם רחמים וכו’ והופך עליהם מידת הדין לרחמים… שע”י אותו הדבר בעצמו, שהיה מקום לשרות עליו הדין ח”ו, נעשה רחמים למעלה ע”י שאותו הדבר מעורר רחמנות למטה …אבל לבוא לרחמנות הגדולה הזאת בהיות האדם נבוך... א”א רק ע”י הנקודה הפנימית של הלב אשר לא ישלוט בה מגע נכרי, ובית הסתרים אינו מקבל טומאה… וזה נתעורר ע”י השופר כי מאן דנפח מתוכו נפח, מעמקא דלבא, וזה ענין תקיעת שופר... דהיינו גנוחי ויליל שזה ענין הרחמנות הנ”ל

@Fred thank you very much!

Shem MiShmuel (son of the Avnei Nezer) Ki Savo 11:

וי"ל שרמז יש בזה לר"ה שבזוה"ק ויהי היום רומז לר"ה, והיינו עפי"מ שהגיד כ"ק אבי אדמו"ר זצללה"ה שזה היום זכרון ליום ראשון שכתוב ויפח באפיו נשמת חיים, כן בכל ר"ה נותנים לאדם חיים חדשים מלובשים בקול השופר

He repeats this idea in several other places. A search in Sefaria with the words ויפח באפיו filtered to Shem MiShmuel should give you an extensive list of the many times he discusses it.

Yes, that seems the one. Many thanks!
